# Outlook.MailItem - method "To" failed Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I use "ThisOutlookSession" and a form "UserFormWorkTime".

**With Outlook 2010 I had no problems. But now with Outlook 2013,** I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Here is my code:

```
'Benutzername für E-Mail auslesen
'MsgBox Session.Accounts.Item(1).UserName
Var = Split(Session.Accounts.Item(1).UserName, ".")
Vorname = Var(0)
Name = Var(1)

' E-Mail erstellen und anzeigen
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

If TextBoxInputWorkStart = "" Then

    With objMail
      .To = TextBoxInputTo
      .CC = TextBoxInputCC
      .Subject = "Arbeitszeit " + TextBoxInputDate + ""
      .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren," & "<br><br>" & "aufgrund " & TextBoxInputReason & " war keine Zeiterfassung möglich." & "<br><br>" & "Ende: " & TextBoxInputWorkEnd & "<br><br>" & "Vielen Dank für das Eintragen" & "<br>" & Vorname & " " & Name
      ' A dialog box is open. Close it and try again => avoid this error, display it modelessly
      Unload Me
      objMail.Display

    End With
```

Comment: What does the message says in English? It seems that this is the line `.To = TextBoxInputTo` that has an issue, did you declare `objMail` properly earlier in the code and didn't post that part?

Comment: Yes, I declared it in ThisOutlookSession: 

    UserFormWorkTime.TextBoxInputTo.Text = "test@test.de"
    UserFormWorkTime.TextBoxInputCC.Text = "test@test.de;test2@test.de"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class to add recipients. The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866951(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Recipients class creates a new recipient in the Recipients collection. The [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703.aspx) property of a new Recipient object is set to the default value for the associated AppointmentItem, JournalItem, MailItem, MeetingItem, or TaskItem object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type.

```
  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
  Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev")  
  myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

Don't forget to use the [Resolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff862796.aspx) or [ResolveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff867165.aspx) methods of the Recipient(s) class to get recipients resolved against the address book.

Do you get any exceptions or errors in the code?

Answer (score 4):

A few things.

1) If this is Outlook VBA and you correctly use `ThisOutlookSession`, then there is no nee to
`Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

2) Always concatenate string s with `&`, do not use `+`

3) Do not conflate the object with its `.Text` value. Instead of `TextBoxInputDate` use `TextBoxInputDate.Text`.

Try the following, slightly adapted code:

```
Dim objMail As MailItem
' E-Mail erstellen und anzeigen

Set objMail = ThisOutlookSession.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail
    .To = TextBoxInputTo.Text
    .CC = TextBoxInputCC.Text
    .Subject = "Arbeitszeit " & TextBoxInputDate.Text & ""
    .HTMLBody = "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren," & "<br><br>" & "aufgrund " & TextBoxInputReason.Text & " war keine Zeiterfassung möglich." & "<br><br>" & "Ende: " & TextBoxInputWorkEnd.Text & "<br><br>" & "Vielen Dank für das Eintragen" & "<br>" & Vorname & " " & Name
    ' A dialog box is open. Close it and try again => avoid this error, display it modelessly
    Unload Me
    objMail.Display
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The error code is RPC_E_DISCONNECTED, which means the out-of-proc COM server terminated while you still had a reference to one of its objects.

This usually happens when the user closes Outlook while your code is automating it.